# Mounting a remote SCP or SFTP share on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, mount, scp, sftp

I use Fuse4X and ForkLift to mount a remote directory (a dev server). I use PHPStorm to open projects and source (`/Volumes/dev/project_path`), but sometimes it happens that Forklift freezes (in Activity Monitor 100 and more percent cpu). To solve this I have to kill Forklift, remount and reopen project.

Any idea or tip for better mounting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option for me is now **[Samba](http://www.samba.org/)**. After install and [adding smb user](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adding-a-user-to-a-samba-smb-share/) it works perfectly. Simply connect in Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server -> smb://server-name/. Bye FUSE and Macfusion!

Comment: This cannot in good conscience be the accepted answer to the question "[How do I] Mount[ing] a remote SCP or SFTP share on Mac"

Comment: You need administrative access to the server to setup Samba.

Comment: I can see how some people might not have thought to make a service account and just use the native file sharing on macos. Also, if anyone ever needs to undo a down vote - flag for moderator to assist with a vote.

Comment: Thanx for the downvote-undo tip.

Answer (score 7):

Seems https://mountainduck.io is where it's at:

> Mountain Duck lets you mount server and cloud storage as a local disk in the Finder.app on Mac and the File Explorer on Windows. Open remote files with any application and work like on a local volume.

If you find other alternatives, add them at https://alternativeto.net/software/mountain-duck/

Answer (score 3):

Two good options, one paid, one free.

### [Transmit](http://panic.com/Transmit/)

Transmit is a long-standing and well-regarded Mac app that handles FTP, SFTP, S3 and WebDAV (possibly other protocols, I'm not sure). It can mount anything you can access as a local volume. $34, but it's the faster way, if you don't mind buying another app.

### FUSE and Macfusion

Download and install [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.com/) and [Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org/). Make sure to check MacFUSE compatibility when installing FUSE for OS X. Open up Macfusion, add a new share with the + button, and you should be set. This is the free option, but it can be a bit fiddly, and I've heard it can be less stable, but I don't have enough experience with it to say for sure.

Comment: ...last commit with Macfusion 3 years ago, first impression not good -- does it work let say for sftp?

Comment: Transmit doesn't support SCP.  However, http://frank.vanpuffelen.net/2008/01/winscp-replacement-for-mac.html

Comment: Transmit still does not support SCP.

Comment: Any server that you can access with SCP should support SFTP, both run over SSH. SCP is non-interactive, so any sort of disk mounting would be a big hack at best.

Comment: I have used Transmit for literal decades at this point, but sadly they no longer offer Transmit Disk (the functionality being discussed here). They are supposedly investigating ways to rewrite it to offer it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try CyberDuck for free: http://cyberduck.ch/

And I found SSHFS: http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Answer (score 1):

Getting OSx for developer -ready, I have heard of the following below.

- Expanddrive [here](http://www.expandrive.com/)
- sshfs with brew (FREE)
- Cyberduck -- insecure Java -implementation, apparently free version [here](http://cyberduck.ch/)
- Transmit [here](http://transmit.en.softonic.com/mac)

And lastly platform-independent -solution that looks most promising because you can export instances:

- Owncloud.com [here](https://owncloud.com/download)

Comment: ...instead of wasting time with brew and proper sshfs -installation, you may want to try some of the apps -- I faced this bug with brew [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13647).

Answer (score 1):

Another option - [Fuse-T](https://www.fuse-t.org/) (no kext, userspace).

```
$ brew tap macos-fuse-t/homebrew-cask
$ brew install fuse-t fuse-t-sshfs

$ sshfs user@server:/directory /mount-here
```

Comment: This answer partially worked for me. I can mount my root filesystem but when opening a file with text edit i get permissions errors: "The document "test.txt" could not be saved. You don't have permission. To view or change permissions, select the item in the finder and choose File > Get Info". Do you  have any ideas? How can I modify my mounted sftp files with text edit? @Mohnish

Answer (score 0):

### FUSE for macOS and SSHFS

You can use [FUSE for macOS](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse) and [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs). There are a few scattered old versions of things on the web and it took me a while to work out where the latest versions of things are:

- FUSE for macOS was originally [macFUSE](https://code.google.com/archive/p/macfuse/) written by Google, but that project is abandoned.
- The osxfuse Github project has [its own version of SSHFS](https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs) which they should really delete - Mac support was merged into the [upstream SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) years ago.
- There is a GUI frontend for this called [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) but it has been abandoned and still uses `macFUSE` rather than `FUSE for macOS`. There are [instructions to make it use `FUSE for macOS` instead](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS).

Also complicating matters, the latest version of upstream SSHFS requires libfuse3, but [FUSE for macOS only provides libfuse2](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/390).

Anyway:

1. Download and install [the latest release of FUSE for macOS](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases).
2. Download and [the latest ***2.x*** release of SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/releases).

Now compile it:

```
tar xvf sshfs-2.10.tar.gz
cd sshfs-2.10
./configure
make
cp sshfs ~/bin/   # (Or whatever)
```

Now you can mount somewhere:

```
sshfs me@host: ~/host
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I was missing a simple front end to sshfs for macOS, I wrote my own GUI app called [SSHFS-Mountlet](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/applications/SSHFS-Mountlet/). It's a bash script using platypus to provide a menu bar icon. You can mount and unmount previously set up connections with a single click. It only works with ssh public key authentication for ease of use and security.

You can [download](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/applications/SSHFS-Mountlet/) it including the source. It is licensed under GNU GPL 2.0. I hope it is useful for some one else as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is not selling pitch but I use [Flow sftp+ftp application](http://fivedetails.com/flow/) to work on my servers.

Comment: ..according to feedback, the developer has abandoned this project hence -1. I don't know whether the feedback is correct but not good feedback in the store.